# Swift - Can't figure out a simple "Mic->Effect->File" chain in AudioKit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I want to do a simple "record user's microphone -> apply an effect -> save to wav file" chain using AudioKit in Swift.

Below is the code I'm trying to use. What I get instead is that I hear the output through the headphones (with pitch effect applied), but output file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```swift
import AudioKit
import AVFoundation
import SoundpipeAudioKit

class AudioRecorder: ObservableObject {
  
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var recoder: NodeRecorder?

    private(set) lazy var outputFileURL: URL = {
        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        return documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("recording.wav")
    }()

    func startRecording() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set up recording session.")
            return
        }

        guard let input = engine.input else {
            print("No audio input found")
            return
        }

        do {
            recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: input, fileDirectoryURL: outputFileURL)
        } catch let err {
            fatalError("\(err)")
        }
        let pitchShifter = PitchShifter(input)
        engine.output = pitchShifter

        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to start audio engine: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        engine.stop()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to stop recording session.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `engine.start()` and `input`? Can you show the record settings? Did you conform `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` delegate?

Comment: @son - I have updated code snippet to include the rest of the file. `engine.start()` comes from AudiotKit's AudioEngine class

Comment: It would help if you add code of a little view with a simple button to start the recording and play the recorded file. I then can try it directly in my Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing following to make it work:

1. Line     `var recoder: NodeRecorder?`
   Change to      `var recorder: NodeRecorder?` // missing r
2. Line `return documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("recording.wav")`  Change to  `return documentsPath`  // NodeRecorder wants a directory, not a file in fileDirectoryURL
3. Add the `pitchShifter` to the audiograph before adding the recorder, as you want to record the shifted audio.
4. Record and save to a .waf in two different steps. NodeRecorder records to a temporary .caf which you then can move or encode and send.
5. NodeRecorder has some built in file management, beware of `shouldCleanupRecordings:` as it's default to true

--

```
let pitchShifter = PitchShifter(input)

do {
    recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: pitchShifter, fileDirectoryURL: outputFileURL, shouldCleanupRecordings:false)
} catch let err {
    fatalError("\(err)")
}
engine.output = pitchShifter
```

Furthermore check out the Cookbook of AudioKit, this example will help: https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/CookbookCommon/Sources/CookbookCommon/Recipes/MiniApps/Recorder.swift

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I still need to figure out how to convert .caf file to .wav, but at least I am getting somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The `NodeRecorder` has been connected to the input, however to start recording you have to call `record()`

```
do {
    try recorder?.record()
}
catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Stop the recording by calling `recorder?.stop()`. Also, noticed that you are feeding the microphone input to the `NodeRecorder`. If you need to write the pitch shifted samples, you have to feed the `pitchShifter` to the `NodeRecorder`.

```
recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: pitchShifter, fileDirectoryURL: outputFileURL)
```